# purpose of class variable in this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading a book about Ruby/Rails and have a question about something simple.  In the method "turn" below, the author uses "self," which refers to the class. However, what is the difference (in terms of what you can and cannot do), if any, if he left off "self" and just did

```
direction = new_direction
```

Code

```
class Car << ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :direction, :presence => true 
  validates :speed, :presence => true

  def turn(new_direction) 

    self.direction = new_direction

  end

end
```

Comment: I'm notnsure why the other answers are ignoring the AR aspect, but your takeaway from those should be that the class methods must be called in order to persist the value. This is a common-enough mistake in Rails code that I'm pointing it in a comment so it isn't lost.

Comment: Also, note that @direction is different yet again, and will also not be persisted.

Comment: all of these answers helped me a bit, don't know who to give the check to.

Comment: Doesn't matter--whichever one provided the most insight. My personal concern is that you understand why self.direction/etc. will update e DB and other forms won't--I don't need anything more than that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` (persisted) vars must be accessed with `self` because of AR's implementation.

Here, the `self` distinguishes a column (DB) variable from a "normal", un-persisted instance property. The difference would be that the value wouldn't be saved in the database on a save or update.

Answer (score 3):

Some background: The existence of "self" in ruby just means the current object. You see class methods like this, where the method is defined on the Class, not the Instance.

```
class Cookbook
  def self.find_recipe
  end
  def is_awesome?
    true
  end
end
```

This `find_recipe` is a method on Cookbook, so you call it by `Cookbook.find_recipe` and you would call is_awesome on an instance by:

```
cookbook = Cookbook.new
puts cookbook.is_awesome?
```

So: The reason `self.direction=` is called is the author does not want to create a variable named direction in the method. If the author had:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :direction
  def turn(new_direction)
    direction = new_direction
  end
end
```

Then you would see:

```
car = Car.new
car.direction = :left
car.turn(:right)
car.direction
 => :left
```

change it to self.direction, and then it will set instance's variable correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This sets a local variable `a` to the value of `b`

```
a = b
```

But this is different:

```
self.a = b
```

This actually runs the `a=` method with `b` as an argument.  It actually means:

```
self.a=(b)
```

Lastly, while methods can be called on `self` with providing `self` as the receiver, the same is *not* true for assignment.  `a = b` will never invoke the `a=` method, and will only ever assign a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7963

```
self.direction = new_direction
```

Assigns the a new value to the 'direction' attribute on the instance of Car, whereas

```
direction = new_direction
```

creates a local variable called 'direction' and returns its value but does not update the Car instance.

So for example I believe the following should happen:

```
class Car << ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :direction, :presence => true 
  validates :speed, :presence => true

  def turn(new_direction) 
    self.direction = new_direction
  end

  def set_speed(new_speed)
    speed = new_speed
  end
end

alf = Car.new

alf.direction = "North"
alf.speed = 1

alf.turn = "South"
alf.set_speed = 5

> alf.direction
=> "South"

> alf.speed
=> 1
```

Comment: o.k, so the speed of "5" doesn't persist because it wasn't set to a class variable, but then why does "alf.speed" return "1" at the end. What causes "1" to persist if it was originally set using an ordinary variable?  can you explain this a bit?

Comment: @Michael there's no persistence here, it's a demo of how set_speed *doesn't* set the persistable column field "speed". Persistence only comes in to play if an AR record is saved or its attributes are updated. See how alf.speed is "1" at the end? That's because set_speed is setting a local "speed", not an instance variable or the column variable.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks i got that, if set_speed sets only a local speed, so is alf.speed = 1 also a local "speed"?

Comment: @Michael No, alf.speed is the persisted/DB "speed" value (or would be persisted if "save" or si liar is called, anyway).

Comment: @DaveNewton but that was my question, what caused it to persist if it wasn't set using self.speed. It was just set as a regular local variable without self so I didn't understand how it persisted. I guess he just didn't "save" it in this example?

Comment: @Michael I think you may be misunderstanding "persisted", it just means "saved to the DB". It's set via "alf.speed = 1". Since it's the same instance of a Car, that value will stay the same unless changed (which set_speed does *not* do). The point of setting the value with "alf.speed" is that it calls a setter that updates thte value that would be saved to the DB if save/etc. is called, as using "self.speed" would do if called inside an instance method of Car.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can we put talk of Saving and Databases to one side? For the purposes of this example, Car might as well just be a plain ruby class and talking about Active Record is just confusing the issue. @Michael: at the risk of repeating my answer, alf is an object with a class of `Car`, `alf.speed=` is a function which updates an attribute called `speed` on `alf` and `alf.set_speed` is effectively just a function which returns the value passed to it without affecting any of the attributes on `alf`.

Comment: To put it another way: the _Scope_ of the variable called `speed` in the `set_speed` method is restricted to that method - the variable is created within that method and is thrown away once the method has returned.